# Data validation stopped working multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, multer, express-validator

I use the `express-validator` to check text fields and `multer` to check avatars. But I have a problem, the `express-validator` stopped checking the text fields, if you leave the field empty, the express validator will not give an error message that the field is empty.

I displayed text fields in a separate variable:

```
import { check, validationResult } from 'express-validator/check';

const validatorSignup = [
    check('user_name').exists().isLength({ min: 4, max: 20 }),
    ....
];
```

Next, I want to check at registration whether all fields are filled by the user and whether the avatar is loaded:

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    try {
        upload(req, res, validatorSignup, (err) => {
            console.log(req.body)
            const errors = validationResult(req.body);
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(422).json({
                    err: errors.array()
                });
            }
      ....
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            err: err
        });
    }
});
```

But I get an error:

```
onFinished(req, function () { next(err) })
                                    ^
TypeError: next is not a function
```

Help solve my problem.

Comment: can you please add the code where the function 'onFinished' is?

Comment: I do not have such a function in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call sequence are messed up, there are two things being wrong here:

1. `upload` is async and try catch will not work any way.
2. `upload` is to be used like middleware and you cannot pass `validatorSignup` like this expecting multer to do the validation. This is why an error is thrown for onFinished because multer expects third argument to be of `(next)=>{}`, not an array.

Therefore your markup should be more like this:

```js
router.post('/signup', upload, validatorSignup, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const errors = validationResult(req.body);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            err: errors.array()
        });
    }
    ...
});
```

Note1: I have not seen `validationResult(req.body);` from documentation, only `validationResult(req);`.

Note2: by default errors in middleware like `upload` and `validatorSignup` will automatically result in 500, if you want to customize the error message (like your JSON with err), check out [Express error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) (Writing error handlers)

Comment: Thanks, I figured out my mistake. But I have a new problem, when a user uploads more than one photo, an error occurs. How can it be processed to give to the user?

Comment: what is the error? do you intend to let user upload more than one photo?

Comment: No, I want to handle the error when the user tried to upload more than one photo. Now when he uploads a photo from me, I get an error `MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter ` How to bang her and give to the user in `json`?

Comment: "[check out Express error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)", basically add another middleware thereafter with signature `(err, req, res, next) => {}`

Comment: I tried this, but the error is not processed. I declared the `errorHandler` function and added `router.use(errorHandler)`. But the results did not work.

Comment: maybe the number of parameters is invalid? it must be 4, if still not working then im out of clue with current context.